# Where is wrong code c# oop in Unity3d

Tags: c#, oop, unity-game-engine

Now I have 2 class in my project.
I want to use method class 2 in class 1.
And this code c#

**Class 1**

```
public class controlBuilding : MonoBehaviour
{
    ScaleModel cScale = new ScaleModel();

    public void Start()
    {

    }

    public void Update()
    {
        cScale.touchScaleB1();
    }

    public void OnGUI()
    {

    }
}
```

**Class 2**

```
public class ScaleModel : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void touchScaleB1()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount >= 2)
        {
            Touch touch1 = Input.touches[0];
            Touch touch2 = Input.touches[1];

            if (touch1.phase == TouchPhase.Moved || touch2.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            {
                float pinchDistance = Vector2.Distance(touch1.position, touch2.position);
                float prevDistance = Vector2.Distance(touch1.position - touch1.deltaPosition,
                                                       touch2.position - touch2.deltaPosition);
                float pinchDistanceDelta = pinchDistance - prevDistance;

                if (pinchDistanceDelta > 0)
                {
                    float mScaleFactor;
                    mScaleFactor = b1_floor1dae.transform.localScale.x;
                    mScaleFactor += 0.0004f;
                    b1_floor1dae.transform.localScale = new Vector3(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
                    b1_floor2dae.transform.localScale = new Vector3(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
                    b1_floor3dae.transform.localScale = new Vector3(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
                    b1_floor4dae.transform.localScale = new Vector3(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
                    b1_floorTop.transform.localScale = new Vector3(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
                    b1_other.transform.localScale = new Vector3(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
                }
                else if (pinchDistanceDelta < 0)
                {
                    float mScaleFactor;
                    mScaleFactor = b1_floor1dae.transform.localScale.x;
                    mScaleFactor -= 0.0004f;
                    b1_floor1dae.transform.localScale = new Vector3(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
                    b1_floor2dae.transform.localScale = new Vector3(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
                    b1_floor3dae.transform.localScale = new Vector3(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
                    b1_floor4dae.transform.localScale = new Vector3(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
                    b1_floorTop.transform.localScale = new Vector3(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
                    b1_other.transform.localScale = new Vector3(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Why I touch on screen is not event ? Where is wrong code ?**

Excuse me.I'm not good English.

Thank you very much for answer.

Comment: Classes derived from Monobehaviour should not be instantiated with new. Instead use [Instantiate](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html).  Have you tried adding some debugging to verify the problem is Input.touches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you want the ScaleModel to be only a utility class :**
Don't inherit it from MonoBehaviour. So you can create it with "new" keyword as a regular class.

**If you want the ScaleModel to be a gameobject component :**
Add your both scripts to the same gameobject and change your first class like this...
(by calling the GetComponent, you are searching for the ScaleModel component on the same game object)

```
public class controlBuilding : MonoBehaviour
{
    ScaleModel cScale;

    public void Start()
    {
        cScale = GetComponent<ScaleModel>();
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        cScale.touchScaleB1();
    }

    public void OnGUI()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you see? You should give details if you need help :)

Comment: When I pinch to zoom and zoom out is not working function touchScaleB1.But when I put code from touchScaleB1 in " public void Update" is working